# Hide navigation bar Swiftui

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, navigationview

I've a problem with the NavigationView in SwiftUI, I've add this code for hide the navigation and works fine but in when scroll the view appear the sticky header how to remove this? thanks!!

```
NavigationView {
...
}
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the navigationBarTitle and navigationBarHidden within the NavigationView will remove the sticky header. Here's the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December","January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(months, id: \.self) { month in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(month: month)) {
                        Text(month)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        //.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let month: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(month)
    }
}
```